# How to create a temporary table in ASP.NET Core MVC using EF Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to create a temporary table in SQL Server?

Whenever I try to create a temporary table, I get this error :

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name '##TempTable'.

This is my code:

```
[NonAction]
public IActionResult InsertData()
{
    _Db._context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CREATE TABLE ##TempTable (Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(50))");
    
    // Insert records into the global temporary table using raw SQL query

    _Db._context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("INSERT INTO ##TempTable (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Jane')");
    
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Each command is a separate session.

Comment: @GertArnold So Please Can You Tell Me the Proper way For Doing it ?

Comment: Start transaction. EF Core do not close connection if transaction is started.